# how to translate this PHP code to PDO form , because i am getting undefined function in PHP 7 (using XAMPP)?

Tags: php

This is my PHP file, but i am getting `fatal error : undefined function mysql_connect`, i have searched it and it looks like i have to use PDO instead of **mysql_connect** on **PHP 7** , and i dont know how so i need help please, I want this code as **PDO**, thanks for your time

```
<?php

// connection , which gives fatal exception : undefined function..

$con = mysql_connect("localhost",'root',''); 

//error handling

if (!$con)

 {

  die("Could not connected".mysql_error());  else 
{

//select the DB name in PhpMyAdmin

  mysql_select_db("tm-mobile",$con);

//Vlidation

if (!empty($_POST['owner_name']) && !empty($_POST['owner_email'])) 
{

  $owner_id=$_POST['owner_id'];

  $owner_name=$_POST['owner_name'];

  $owner_email=$_POST['owner_email'];

  $owner_password=$_POST['owner_password'];

  $market_name=$_POST['market_name'];

//SQL statement

$sql =  "UPDATE owner_table SET owner_id = '$owner_id',owner_name = 

  '$owner_name' , owner_email = '$owner_email', owner_password = 

  '$owner_password'  ,  market_name = '$market_name' ";

  $re = mysql_query ($sql,$con);

//Close the Connection

mysql_close();

   }

}

?>
```

Comment: Already close voted for another reason but here is same user same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816577/how-to-translate-this-php-code-to-pdo-code-for-php-7-because-i-am-getting-undef

Comment: Posting again and again will not help you

Comment: don't try to memories the code, you need to look for it and know each function what it does.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb', 'root', 'password');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
    if (!empty($_POST['owner_name']) && !empty($_POST['owner_email'])) {
        $owner_id = $_POST['owner_id'];
        $owner_name = $_POST['owner_name'];
        $owner_email = $_POST['owner_email'];
        $owner_password = $_POST['owner_password'];
        $market_name = $_POST['market_name'];

        $statement = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE `owner_table` SET `owner_id` = :owner_id, `owner_name` = :owner_name,
                              `owner_email` = :owner_email, `owner_password` = :owner_password, market_name = :market_name;');
        $statement->bindParam(':owner_id', $owner_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->bindParam(':owner_name', $owner_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':owner_email', $owner_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':owner_password', $owner_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':market_name', $market_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
        echo $statement->rowCount();
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Cannot connect: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

here it is, take look at some tutorials, for example http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers and also use `where` in `INSERT/REPLACE/UPDATE/DELETE` queries because it can be dangerous